# Can the 'final' keyword be made conditional to C++11 in an API?

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-compatibility

Is it a good idea to enable the `final` C++11 keyword conditionally to the standard version in a header file? I'm thinking of something like:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#   define MY_FINAL final
#else
#   define MY_FINAL
#endif

// ...

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int f() MY_FINAL;
};
```

I have two doubts here:

1. whether the method with and without `final` will be ABI-compatible (it seems reasonable to assume so to me, and a quick check with `g++` confirms that),
2. that the C++98 compiler won't complain when someone tries to override the method. But I believe that documenting the method as *don't override it* should handle this.

Comment: At the very least, this is going to violate the principle of least surprise.

Comment: Define "ABI-compatible"? Are you wondering if it will change the ABI if it is compiled as C++11 instead of C++03?

Comment: @NicolBolas: yes, exactly that. I am wondering if the library compiled as C++11 will be compatible with C++98 apps, and the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `final` should never affect the ABI, it only affects whether the translation from C++ source code should succeed or fail, it has no *required* effect on the generated code.

2) You can make the compiler complain even in C++98 mode if you are prepared to use some non-standard extensions. G++ 4.7 supports `__final` in C++98 mode with the same meaning:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#   define MY_FINAL final
#elif (__GNUC__ > 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7)
#   define MY_FINAL __final
#else
#   define MY_FINAL
#endif
```

I think clang++ accepts `final` in C++98 mode, but issues a warning.

Comment: `it only affects whether the translation from C++ source code should succeed or fail, it has no affect on the generated code.` I believe it provides an optimization opportunity as well, thus affecting the generated code. Well, unless you meant only the implementation and not the caller code.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. I should have said it has no effect on the ABI, and no _required_ effect on the code - optimisations that don't change the meaning are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

`#`2 is pretty given. I'm not so sure about `#1`, though. Logically, the C++11 compiler is well within it's rights to inline calls to `f()` on a Derived object, for example, and not issue a virtual call, whereas a C++03 compiler is compelled to issue a virtual call. I'm not sure if this will actually make any difference, but it might.

Comment: Apart from being faster it makes no difference that users can detect, and so under the "as if" rule C++03 compilers are not obliged to make a virtual call when the final overrider is known e.g. when the dynamic type of the object is known.  In any case, that doesn't affect the ABI.

Comment: If a `Derived*` was pointing to a class in C++03 which did override this function, the C++11 compiler would not call the more derived version and the C++03 compiler would.

Comment: How would the more-derived class override it? That code would not compile in C++11. And the case I gave is where the dynamic type is known, so the compiler knows which override is the final overrider.